# Objective C - Write png file to remote file share

Tags: objective-c, data-transfer, mount-point

I want to move a png file from user's Mac desktop to a mounted Windows file share. I can't seem to be able to make the remote path work with the code I'm using.

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath: stringFilePath  toPath: @"/NameOfFileShare/Path/To/Folder/FileName.png" error: NULL]  == YES)
 NSLog (@"Copy successful");
 else
 NSLog (@"Copy failed");
```

I've tried many variations of the remote file path. I can use the code above successfully if paths are local. How can I move a file to a remote share???

Comment: I don't have access to my Mac right now but to my memory which might be wrong, the mounted windows network folders are being mounted under /Volumes/NameofSharedResource/RestOfPath/foo.png, therefore try accessing from /Volumes/...

Comment: Could of sworn I used /Volumes in my many permutations of trying. Must of had something else wrong at the time. Thanks for pointing that out. It made me revisit it and it now works.

Comment: Great. Happy I could help. For others to be able to use the answer I will post an actual answer to your question then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS (OS X) loads the network drivers under `/Volumes` alongside other drivers. Therefore your code should look something like this:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath: stringFilePath  toPath: @"/Volumes/NameOfFileShare/Path/To/Folder/FileName.png" error: NULL]  == YES)
NSLog (@"Copy successful");
else
NSLog (@"Copy failed");
```

Pay attention to the path that starts with `/Volumes`

It should work now.